# What session manager should I use?

Tags: linux, session-manager

I'm not using any desktop environment, but I need a session manager mainly to gracefully halt the system. It seems I can't find any solution around. The only one is `xsm`, but I got no luck with it.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Write your own.  Use bash as a shell.  You can call setup and teardown scripts from `.bash_login` and `.bash_logout.`  Include a `startx` command in `bash_login`.

This will be helpful: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/execution-sequence-for-bash_profile-bashrc-bash_login-profile-and-bash_logout/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a session manager as opposed to a login manager or display manager? If not, look at [SliM](http://slim.berlios.de/), [Qingy](http://qingy.sourceforge.net/), [cdm](http://cdm.ghost1227.com/) or [xdm](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xdm.1.html).

Comment: I'm using `xdm`, but it doesn't care about killing processes on logout. Maybe I'm misunderstanding some concepts... Let's say I need *something* that gracefully kills my processes when I close my window manager.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [xfce4 session manager](http://www.xfce.org/projects/xfce4-session). The xfce4 desktop is modular, and many components can be used stand-along. Although you may also need the settings manager.

Comment: `xfce4-session` has several dependencies (among the others: `aumix`, `xfdesktop4`, `xscreensaver`, `tango-icon-theme`, etc.) and I can't see how they can be related to session management. I was looking for something different. But maybe I'll give it a try.

Comment: @cYrus Well, xfce4 is a pretty good environment in its own right. Try it, maybe you'll like it.